# How to read data from an Excel worksheet Table into a JSON format using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, excel, xlsx

I am using the XSLS library to read an Excel file where my sheet name is "SheetName" and fetch the data from it in json format. I now want to modify my function to read the data from a table in the same sheet. I am not able to find an interface to do so. I see that sheet_to_json has a parameter range but for that to work I need the Table boundaries. Please could someone help if done before.

```
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);     
    reader.onload = function(e) {
    var data = e.target.result;         
        try {       
            var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                type : 'binary'
            });                 
            var result = {};
            //reading data of sheet named Depdendency
            var jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets["SheetName"], 
                {
                defval: '', 
                header: 'A'      /// Providing header='A' for flexibility as by default the first row is treated as the key names in JSON data     
                                 /// This will help keeping JSON data keyed on default column names of Excel 'A', 'B', 'C' ... making data manipulation easy    
                // range: 'A3:E16' could be helpful 
                }
                );
```

Thanks a tonz in advance.

I read the documentation of XLSX but didnt find a way to do so but I suspect I might be overlooking something as it is a very basic requirement.